# Is there a namespace I can set for my JiBX customizations

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, xml-namespaces, jibx

Currently, I have the following JiXB customizations file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schema-set>
  <schema name="./target.xsd" >
    <complexType name="type" ... />
  </schema>
</schema-set>
```

This works nicely with the jibx-maven-plugin, and the customizations work as expected. However, to use code assist in IntelliJ Idea, I would like to define a XML namespace for the root element. If I point it to the `codegen-customizations.xsd` file in the JiBX site, I get an error.

```
<schema-set xmlns="http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schemas/codegen-customizations.xsd">
```

The error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] No unmarshaller for element "{http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schemas/codegen-customizations.xsd}schema-set" (line 2, col 84)
```

Furthermore, intellij shows the correct completion options, but complains `Cannot find declaration of element 'schema-set'`.

Is there a xml namespace I can use for my jibx customizations?